# How to get scandinavian letters ä and ö in a plot in Matlab R2012b

Tags: matlab, character-encoding, plot

I'm plotting some of my analysis results in Matlab. My operating system is Ubuntu 13.10. I try to add the letter "ä" into the title of Matlab figure, but what I get is the following:

[image]

here is my code:

```
function plotResults(data)
% FUNCTION plotResults(data)

ind = 1;
x = 1:length(data{1, end});

for i = 1:length(data)
    if mod(i, 5) == 1
        figure(ind)
        plot(x, data{i, end}, 'b--')
        hold on
    elseif mod(i, 5) == 2
        plot(x, data{i, end}, 'c--')
    elseif mod(i, 5) == 3
        plot(x, data{i, end}, 'r--')
    elseif mod(i, 5) == 4
        plot(x, data{i, end}, 'g--')
    elseif mod(i, 5) == 0
        plot(x, data{i, end}, 'm--')
        legend('Random', 'Hill climb', 'Greedy hill climb', 'Stochastic hill climb', 'Hill climb --> Stochastic hill climb')
        grid on
        xlabel('Aika')
        ylabel('Kustannus')
        title(['Käsiä : ' num2str(data{i, 2}) ', Suuttimia : ' num2str(data{i, 3})])
        ind = ind + 1;
    end
end
```

Any idea how to get the "ä" show up correctly? =)

Thnx for any help!

P.S.

MWE:

```
plot(1:10, 1:10)
title(['{\"a}{\"o} ' num2str(5) ], 'Interpreter', 'latex')
```

Comment: I think this one did it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11212673/1565754, even though the number 5 looks a bit funny when this 'Interpreter', 'latex' is applied.

Comment: did you try adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in the beginning of your file?

Comment: @HerrActress isn't that Python? :)

Comment: Wooops, I did not read the tags and at the first sight the code looked python. my bad :)

Comment: +1 @HerrActress No probs ;D thanx anyway! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LaTeX:

```
title(['K\"asi\"a : ' num2str(data{i, 2}) ', Suuttimia : ' num2str(data{i, 3})])
```

See [Is it possible to display unicode in MATLAB plot labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651238/is-it-possible-to-display-unicode-in-matlab-plot-labels) and [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57743/how-to-write-a-and-other-umlauts-and-accented-letters-in-bibliography%20for%20more%20details)

Or try the unicode approach:

```
title(['K', char(228), 'si', char(228) : ' ....
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for your help! =) Unfortunately didn't work...Now instead of the funny symbols in the image above it printed "\a. {\"a} also didn't do it. It just prints {\"a}....

Comment: +1 Your links led me to the answer, thank you =) I need to set 'Interpreter', 'latex' in the title-command =)

Comment: Try adding `,'interpreter','tex'` to the end of your `title` function

Comment: +1 Yes, it did it =) The letter 5 looks a bit funny (maybe Ubuntu has something to do with it, because the plots look different in Ubuntu Matlab than Windows Matlab). but ä and ö are working =) Oh by the way @Dan 'tex' didn't work for me, it needed to be 'latex'

Comment: Hmmm.. how about `['K$$\"a$$si$$\"a$$ : ' num2str(data{i, 2}) ', Suu...`? Or else you might try the unicode approach?

Comment: the $$ approach did not do it, Matlab gave: Warning: Unable to interpret LaTeX string "K$$\"a$$si$$\"a$$ : 5,
Suuttimia : 5"

Comment: @jjepsuomi try the unicode way, just posted an example

Comment: Sorry, unicode didn't do it either, it gave the same results as the original approach. I posted minimal working example, which mimics my title code =)

Comment: I think I'll go with 'Interpreter', 'latex'-approach, it seems the best so far =) Not perfect (because it makes 5 look funny), but I'll live with it =) Thank you for your effort