# how to display numbers in scientific notation in plot legends in Matlab?

Tags: string, matlab, plot, latex, legend

I have two float variables, let's say they are `phi = 1.34e8` and `beta = -2.7e-6`. How do I display both results in a plot label in latex scientific notation over two lines? I want the plot label to look like (in latex font):

```
\phi = 1.34 x 10^8
\beta = -2.7 x 10^-6
```

And what about I have other variables for error, e.g. `phi_err = 7.1e7`, and I want the legend to look like:

```
\phi = (1.34 +/- 0.71) x 10^8
```

Edit:
My current Matlab code:

```
txt1 = texlabel(['n2=',num2str(n2)]);
txt2 = texlabel(['beta=',num2str(beta)]);
figure(1)
plot(...)
text(0.7,0.8,{txt1,txt2},'Units','normalized')
```

And the plot text looks like the upper part of the attached figure. How do I display the text in scientific notation with the multiply sign and the base 10 instead of `e`? Also, if I want to add the error (let's say I set in Matlab `beta=[-2.7e-6, 1.2e-6]` where `beta(1)` is the value and `beta(2)` is the error), then show should I modify the above code so that the result looks like the lower part of the attached figure? For the example I give, how do I extract `2.7` and `1.2` before the `e`? And what if they are of different order of magnitude, e.g. the error is `1.2e-7`, which means in the displayed text I have to change it from `1.2e-7` to `0.12e-6` and combine the error and the beta value.

[image]

Comment: do you mean that you plot two groups of data, and you want the legend to be `phi=...`, `beta=...`, in latex format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Latex fonts in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212172/latex-fonts-in-matlab)

Comment: @Adiel It doesn't matter how many groups of data or plots I have. I want to display the values in scientific numbers with the multiplication sign and base 10 instead of the 'e'. I want to show the error as well, and have two separate lines.

Comment: Ok, after the edit it's much clearer. I thought that you want a `legend` as in the title of your question, so I asked about thr data.